# WSO2 Api Manager(wso2am-4.0.0) - Is the default token endpoint changed in wso2am-4.0.0?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

In the latest WSO2 Api Manager, the default token endpoint seems to have changed to https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token

In the previous versions, the token endpoint was https://localhost:8243/token and invoking this endpoint generates a 404 resource not found error.

Is it possible to enable the previous token endpoint in the latest WSO2 Api Manager or is the oauth2 token endpoint the default to be used?

Comment: The token endpoint was changed to https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token from API-M 4.0.0 onwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all the APIM versions, OAuth2 token endpoint is `https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token`.

Before APIM 4.0.0 version, we have added a new proxy API to the gateway which will route the requests received to  `https://localhost:8243/token` to the original token endpoint `https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token`. If you check the `<APIM_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api` directory in a APIM version before 4.0.0, you can find several endpoints that are proxied through gateway (`_TokenAPI_.xml`,`_RevokeAPI_.xml` etc).

From 4.0.0, we have removed this extra hop(`_TokenAPI_.xml`) for token call and asked users to directly use the actual token endpoint (`https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token`).

If you need previous experience in APIM 4.0.0 version, just by adding the `_TokenAPI_.xml` to the `<APIM_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api` directory, you can use `https://localhost:8243/token` endpoint.

For you reference, I have copied the same XML here.

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="_WSO2AMTokenAPI_" context="/token">
   <resource methods="POST" url-mapping="/*" faultSequence="_token_fault_">
      <inSequence>
         <property name="uri.var.portnum" expression="get-property('keyManager.port')" />
         <property name="uri.var.hostname" expression="get-property('keyManager.hostname')" />
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <http uri-template="https://{uri.var.hostname}:{uri.var.portnum}/oauth2/token">
                  <timeout>
                     <duration>60000</duration>
                     <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
                  </timeout>
               </http>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send />
      </outSequence>
   </resource>
   <handlers>
      <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerCacheExtensionHandler" />
      <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.common.SynapsePropertiesHandler" />
   </handlers>
</api>
```

Save this to an XML file named `_TokenAPI_.xml` and add it to the above directory. After this, you can use `https://localhost:8243/token` to obtain a token.

### Update

For APIM 4.1.0 onwards, you have to add the new file created to the skip list. Use the following config at the deployment.toml

```
[apim.sync_runtime_artifacts.gateway.skip_list]
apis = ["_TokenAPI_.xml"]
```

Without this config, each restart will clear the newly created XML file.

Comment: I have faced the same issue above 
However when I restart APIM 4.x.0 , 
_TokenAPI_.xml file is removed everytime. Is there any option?

Answer (score 2):

In versions before API-M 4.0.0, the token endpoint was still `https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token`. But a proxy (`https://localhost:8243/token`) was used to invoke this endpoint. You will be able to see this by viewing the `_TokenAPI_.xml` file in `<API-M_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api` directory.

From API-M 4.0.0 onwards, this proxy has been removed and the token endpoint (`https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token`) is invoked directly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Is it possible to proxy this url in the new APIM as well instead of directly invoking the token url?